# Error starting Firefox on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, firefox, ubuntu-for-android

I just installed Ubuntu using UserLAnd on my phone. I installed Firefox and tried to launch it via the terminal. I got the error

`[18567, Main Thread] WARNING: failed to open shm: Permission denied: file /build/firefox-dnXMb4/firefox-70.0+build2/ipc/chromium/src/base/shared_memory_posix.cc, line 250`

`Segmentation fault`

I used `apt purge firefox` then reinstalled it. I tried to launch Firefox from the terminal again and got the same error.

Additional info:
Root user,  Android,  UserLAnd w/ xsdl Ubuntu 18.04 lts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did a bit of digging. I found [this guide](https://github.com/CypherpunkArmory/UserLAnd/wiki/FAQ#installing-firefox-on-ubuntu) and it works flawlessly.

```
apt update
apt install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
apt update
apt install firefox-esr
firefox-esr
```

Comment: I needed to run these commands as `sudo` everywhere for this to work.